# redirecting to comment section after login is not working in django

Tags: python, django

it saves and displays comments on the options.html page if the user is already logged in but when the user logs in after comment section redirects to the login page it displays the value error as this: 
**NoReverseMatch at /rank/best-trekking-destination-in-nepal/comment/ 

Reverse for 'comment' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['rank/(?P[^/]+)/comment/$'] 

Request Method: GET

Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/rank/best-trekking-destination-in-nepal/comment/

Django Version: 2.1.5 

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch 

Exception Value:

Reverse for 'comment' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['rank/(?P[^/]+)/comment/$']**

> urls.py

```
 path('<slug>/',views.options,name='options'),
 path('<slug>/comment/',views.comment,name='comment'),
```

> views.py

```
def options(request,slug):
    category = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
    category.views += 1
    category.save()
    options = category.option_set.all().order_by('-votes')
    try:
        for option in options:
            option.has_voted = option.vote_set.filter(voter=request.user).exists()
    except:
        options = category.option_set.all().order_by('-votes')


    form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'rank/options.html', {'options': options,'form':form,'title': 'options','category':category})



 @login_required(redirect_field_name='next',login_url='rank:login')
def comment(request,slug):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.category = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Comment Posted.')
            return redirect('rank:options', slug)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'rank/options.html', {'form': form})

def my_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        username = form['username'].value()
        password = form['password'].value()
        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user:
            login(request,user)
            redirect_url = request.GET.get('next','rank:home')
            return redirect(redirect_url)
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Invaid Username or Password')

    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request,'rank/login.html',{'form':form})
```

> options.html

```
{% extends "rank/base.html" %}
 <title>{% block title %}{{title}}{% endblock title%}</title>
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% block content %}
<center><br>
     <ol type="1">
          <center>{% bootstrap_messages %}</center>
    {% for option in options %}

     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 mb-6">
              <div class="card h-100">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <b><li>
                  <img src="/media/{{option.image}}" width="400" height="300">
                 <h4>{{option.name}}
                  </h4>
                  <h5 class="card-text">{{ option.details}}</h5>
                      <h5>{{ option.votes }} votes</h5>
                       {% if option.has_voted %}
                             <p class="btn btn-success">Voted</p>
                       {% else %}
                            <form action="{% url 'rank:vote' option.slug %}" method="post">
                           {% csrf_token %}
                       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Vote" >
                       </form>
                       {% endif %}

                         </li></b>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                  <small class="text-muted"></small>
                </div>


              </div>
                </div>
         {% empty %}
    <div class="card w-100">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4>Item not available</h4>
    </div>
    </div>

    {% endfor %}
     </ol>

<h3>{{ category.comment_set.all|length}} comments</h3>
    <hr>
            {% for c in category.comment_set.all %}
                  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 mb-6">
                     <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                         <b>{{ c.user.username}} </b>&nbsp {{c.created|timesince}} ago
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">{{ c.comment}}</p>
              </div>

            </div>
            {% endfor %}

    <hr>
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 mb-6">
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'rank:comment' category.slug %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
            {% bootstrap_form form %}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Post Comment">
            </form>
     </div>



</center>




{% endblock content%}
```

Comment: please don't replace an error with a completely different one - it means that answers don't make sense any more.

Answer (score 1):

you `comment` function in `views.py` is incomplete. you don't handle `GET` and other types of request in there:

```
@login_required(redirect_field_name='next',login_url='rank:login')
def comment(request,slug):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.category = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Comment Posted.')
            return redirect('rank:options',slug)   
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request,'...some_template',{'form':form})
```

**UPDATE**: your next error `NoReverseMatch` is occured because vairable `category` (and also `options`) not send from views to the `options.html` template and therefor it is null in the template (`arguments '('',)' not found`). you can fix that like this:

```
@login_required(redirect_field_name='next',login_url='rank:login')
def comment(request,slug):
   if request.method == "POST":
       form = CommentForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           comment = form.save(commit=False)
           comment.category = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
           comment.user = request.user
           comment.save()
           messages.success(request, 'Comment Posted.')
           return redirect('rank:options', slug)
   else:
       form = CommentForm()
   category = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
   options = category.option_set.all().order_by('-votes')
   return render(request, 'rank/options.html', {'options': options,'form':form,'title': 'options','category':category})
```

Comment: it means i can directly redirect to the options.anyway thanks for your help .

Answer (score 0):

```
@login_required(redirect_field_name='next',login_url='rank:login')
def comment(request,slug):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.category = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Comment Posted.')
            return redirect('rank:options',slug)

    return redirect('some default view')
```

You need to add a view to each branch of computation if your POST request view fails or the form is not valid then a view is not returned. I put a line of code you need to finish off.

Comment: i have made some changes can you please look at my code once

Comment: Don't go back to return render(request, 'rank/options.html', {'form': form}) if its a GET request, go to a page saying that the form is invalid. You are going to option.html which is handled by your options def and that's throwing the error.

Comment: but it can post the comment and displays no error  if the user is already logged in

Comment: Ah I see, you don't want it to change page? you can use a JsonResponse object and then update the comment section by refreshing the page with something like a document.location.reload() function.